# Angularjs dropdown text need to be showing as a title of the dropdown

Tags: angularjs, dropdownbox

I have a requirement where I need to show the text of angularjs dropdown **(Not value)** in the title tag of the dropdown box. My angular code is like this :

```
  <select id="inputID" name="inputName" 
  ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in genders" 
  ng-model="model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code.value" class="form-control input-sm">
   <option value="">Select...</option> </select>
```

As the dropdown is being generated dynamical, the value of the options and the text in the options are different. in the title tag I am able to get the value with `title={{model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code.value}}` but I need text not the value.

anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you use a repeat over genders and create the options yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCgETznZgs5URzQteXy6?p=preview)

```
<select id="inputID" title={{model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code.display}} name="inputName" ng-options=" item.display for item in genders" 
ng-model="model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
<strong>Selected value:</strong> {{model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code.value}}
```